Dehumidifier with pump
Will a dehumidifier still allow water to flow out using gravity if the pump fails? Or will pump failure stop that route of water flow and only fill the bucket?

Gravity draining needs a downward slope all the way.  Good for first/second floor placement that can drain down to ground.  Pump might allow it, but usually better if a pump was not in the way.
